# Setting state inside a useEffect function is losing state

Tags: reactjs

I am having a bit of difficulty solving this issue. I'm trying to build a Wordle clone and I ran into an interesting problem.

I am building a character map and setting the value inside of state. I call a function after I have successfully validated the user's input. The character map is still being set to its original state when I try to access it programmatically. It's like the `useEffect` never happened.

When I put a `console.log(characterMap)`, outside the function call I can see the value being updated, but the function that I call still holds on to the original state. I was able to work around this by using a `useRef`.  I really want to understand why my functions aren't able to see the current state.

Here is a small code snippet:

```
 useEffect(() => {
   
    let characterMap = {};
    //map the position of the the random word and store it in an object
    const randomWord = "known";

    //create a character map store the position of the character in the word and handle the case of duplicate characters
    for (let i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
      if (characterMap[randomWord[i]]) {
        characterMap[randomWord[i]].push(i);
      } else {
        characterMap[randomWord[i]] = [i];
      }
    }
    
    characterMap.answer = randomWord;
    console.log("setting", characterMap);
    setDictionary(characterMap); <--- cannot access this on a function call. But I can see it if I put a console before the return
    characterMapRef.current = characterMap;
  }, []);
```

In the above code snippet, I am setting the character map but I cannot access the value inside of a function. Using a ref, I can work around it.  Here is a sandbox if anyone is interested.

https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-flower-l1f752?file=/src/App.js:1675-1689

Comment: couldn't find any `setDictiona...` . ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2lYJ.png

Comment: As mentioned by Maifee Ul Asad, I'm also unable to see that state item (`setDictionary`)  in the linked sandbox. Can you either update the sandbox or the embedded code snippet?

One aside, you're using the same name for the state item (characterMap) and the new variable in `useEffect` (characterMap). You may want to consider a different name for the temp variable in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a name collision trying to use `characterMap` as a temporary variable in the `useEffect`, because you already declared it as your state variable.
You can't update state without using the settter function.  Change the temporary variable to something else like `charMap`.  It should work.  I am seeing no issues in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-microservice-wmp6p3)

I also removed the brackets around `[i]` as the value of the map property.  Unless you want to have a bunch of arrays in your character map...